# Elsa child workflow doesn't return outcomes

Tags: elsa-workflows

I have parent and child Elsa workflows. The outcomes of "RunWorkflow" configured like this:

[image]

When child executed I can see the "ClientIsBankrupt" outcome in the child instance journal.

[image]

But when I'm checking the instance journal of the parent I see only "NotFound" outcome

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: This could be a bug. Please open an issue on GitHub, mentioning the version of Elsa you're using, and steps to reproduce this behavior. If you're not already using the latest 2.13 release, it is recommended to give that a try first.